# Command call from script does not wait for previous command to complete

Tags: shell-script

I have a (bash) script that ends like:

```
drive push 2>&1
wait
echo "Backed up."
```

When called on terminal, the `drive push` command generates output `Resolving` first and then cursor animation for twenty seconds and then prints `No changes detected.`. The script is called to log to a file. And the log file never shows the `No changes detected.`. It always has:

```
Resolving
Backed up.
```

What's going on here? Why can't I capture the `No changes detected.` message? How can I capture it?

Comment: `2>&1` is the only redirection. Shouldn't this capture both error and success messages?

Comment: It's possible that the `drive push` command only outputs the "progress meter" when its output goes to a terminal

Comment: With this code, `wait` is not useful. Typically you would use `wait` to wait for *background* jobs to complete, and the `drive` command is running in the foreground.

Comment: I wonder if `drive` only outputs the progress meter if it's run interactively in a terminal